# How to create multiline QR code using bartender?

Tags: excel, bartender

I am trying to generate multiline QR code in `Bartender`. I am using excel file as data source and take 3 filed for testing first. It successfully generate QR code but when I scan all text shows in a single line but I want it to be in 3 fiend in 3 separate line. I have used `Carriage Return` control character `<<CR>>` after 1 data field. Below is QR code properties settings.

[image]

When I scan the `QR Code` image then it gives me following output.

```
No_LAN_IP90:61:AE:BC:5B:01FAC-Laptop-044
```

My Expected output is

```
No_LAN_IP
90:61:AE:BC:5B:01
FAC-Laptop-044
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

> I have Tagged the post as `Excel` because I am using excel file as data source. May be someone excel expert may know the fact.

Comment: I have Tagged the post as Excel because I am using excel file as data source. May be someone excel expert may know the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LF (Line Feed) instead of CR should solve the problem.

--edit--

After rereading your problem I saw I missed something. You are using the example data field to add a LF which will not be used while printing. In the properties screen you have a tab "Transforms" which has an option to add a suffix and/or prefix. If you put the LF in the suffix field for your first and second line your problem should be solved.

Comment: Ok. Let me check and confirm you.

Comment: Problem is not solved yet with your previous answer. I do not try your edited answer. I will try and feedback here.

Comment: That solve my issue. Thanks a lot dear! (Accept + Upvote)